# Do the MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) have different cooling systems depending on the GPU

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, temperature

I read [here](https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/07/24/round-up-user-solutions-for-thermal-throttling-of-the-i9-2018-macbook-pro) that the thermal throttling of the i7 and i9 on the latest MBP (2018, 15-inch) can be significant.

I also got information that the cooling system is different when the MBP is upgraded with the VEGA GPU: is this correct?

This would mean that paying the extra for the VEGA GPU could also have a positive impact on the CPU performance, and thus big a global gain.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this picture answers your question, my previous post was absolutely wrong, that's why i deleted it.

[image: MBP 2018 15" Vega 20 vs. 560X]

Comment: Could you state in words what the answer is? Awesome pictures, but defining choke, and how a GPU heat sync would cool the CPU might be worth stating in words or bullet points.

Comment: But isn’t the heatsink just bigger so it covers the larger GPU? I second @bmike’s question. what does a bigger choke do?

Comment: The CPU is cooled the same way on both versions so even if you go for the VEGA version, your CPU will be as 'cool/hot' as the 560X version.
The GPU has a bigger heatsink because it is bigger than the 560X one.

Comment: I don't find a good explanation of 'choke' right away, but from what I can see/feel, is that it's some kind of composite material...
Sorry that I can't give you a better explanation. :-(